# Reload specific tableview cell with updating array model locally

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am working on one application, in which email list display in tableview. Every email contains one of state from three state like paid,pending and dispute.This data I get from webservice response. If email state is paid then i can change state to pending or dispute on click of pending or dispute buttons. If state is already paid then user can't do any  action on paid button.

Now suppose I change email state from pending to paid by calling webservice that time i want to reload that specific cell with replacing state for that model locally.

How can I achive this.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : HomeTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! HomeTableViewCell
    if arrayData.count > 0 && arrayData.count > indexPath.row {
    var objemail = self.arrayData.object(at: indexPath.row) as? NewHomeModel
    if objemail?.unread == 1 {
        cell.lblEmailSender.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.lblEmailDescription.textColor = UIColor.black
    }else{
        cell.lblEmailSender.textColor = UIColor.gray
        cell.lblEmailDescription.textColor = UIColor.gray
    }
    if objemail?.fileStatus == 1 {
        cell.imgAttachment.isHidden = false
    }else{
        cell.imgAttachment.isHidden = true
    }
    cell.lblEmailSender.text = objemail?.from
    cell.lblEmailHeading.text = objemail?.subject
    cell.lblEmailDescription.text = objemail?.body
    var pending = objemail?.pending
    if (pending == 0) {
        cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        cell.btnPending.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.penddingClick(_:)), for:.touchUpInside )
    }
    else
    {
        cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
    if objemail?.dispute == 0 {
        cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        cell.btnDispute.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.disputeClick(_:)), for:.touchUpInside )
    }
    else
    {
        cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
    if(objemail?.paid == 0)
    {
        cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        cell.btnPaid.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.paidClick(_:)), for:.touchUpInside )
    }
    else
    {
        cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)

    }
    }
    return cell
}
struct NewHomeModel {
var body: String?
var date : String?
var dispute: Int?
var fileStatus: Int?
var from: String?
var msg_id: String?
var paid: Int?
var pending: Int?
var subject: String?
var thread_id: String?
var unread : Int?
var nextToken : String?

init(jsonData: [String: Any]) {
    body = jsonData["body"] as? String ?? ""
    date = jsonData["date"] as? String ?? ""
    dispute = jsonData["dispute"] as? Int ?? 0
    fileStatus = jsonData["fileStatus"] as? Int ?? 0
    from = jsonData["from"] as? String ?? ""
    msg_id = jsonData["msg_id"] as? String ?? ""
    paid = jsonData["paid"] as? Int ?? 0
    pending = jsonData["pending"] as? Int ?? 0
    subject = jsonData["subject"] as? String ?? ""
    thread_id = jsonData["thread_id"] as? String ?? ""
    unread = jsonData["unread"] as? Int ?? 0
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your `Email` model looks something like,

```
class Email {
    var message: String
    var state: CellState

    init(message: String, state: CellState) {
        self.message = message
        self.state = state
    }
}
```

where `CellState` is an `enum` that represents the `states` of a `cell`  - `paid, pending, dispute`, i.e.

```
enum CellState {
    case paid, pending, dispute
}
```

Firstly, you must not write the configuration code of a `cell` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method. A `cell's` configuration must be written in the `cell` itself, i.e.

```
class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var buttonTapHandler: (()->())?
    private var email: Email?

    func configure(with email: Email) {
        self.email = email
        switch email.state {
        case .paid:
            self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
        case .pending:
            self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)
        case .dispute:
            self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onTapPendingButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if self.email?.state != .pending {
            self.email?.state = .pending
            self.buttonTapHandler?()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onTapDisputeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if self.email?.state != .dispute {
            self.email?.state = .dispute
            self.buttonTapHandler?()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onTapPaidButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if self.email?.state != .paid {
            self.email?.state = .paid
            self.buttonTapHandler?()
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code,

1. `buttonTapHandler` - handles the `reload` of the `cell` whenever the `cell's` `state` is changed after tapping any of the `paid/pending/dispute buttons`. We'll see how it can be used further.
2. `configure(with:)` - handles the `UI` of `cell` based in its `current state`.
3. `button tap actions` - change the `cell's` `state` based on which `button` is tapped. Also the `buttonTapHandler` is called to update the `UI`.

Your `ViewController` looks like,

```
class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    var emails = [Email]()
    //rest of the code....

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.emails.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        let email = self.emails[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: email)
        cell.buttonTapHandler = {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

In the above code, the most important that is where we're setting the `cell's` `buttonTapHandler`, i.e.

```
cell.buttonTapHandler = {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

This `handler` will be called everytime you tap on a `button` in the `cell` at `indexPath` and that particular `cell` will be `reloaded`.

Comment: Yes I did. But you must use `enum` to identify your `state` instead of `Int`. That's more relevant here

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows):

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPathOfTheCellToBeReloaded], with: .automatic)
```

This is Swift code. Not sure what you need as you specified both Swift and Objective-C in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could reload the model data locally and the call `tableView.reloadRows(at: IndexPath, with: UITableViewRowAnimation)` which would reload the cell with the new data you updated on your model objects.